# Change ListView Forecolor depending on condition

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm new to WPF so currently pretty confused on the concept.
I have a stock program that I want to change the fore color of that cell depending if the stock price went UP or DOWN.

This is my current code (Omitted few things):

```
public class Stock : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Stock()
    {
        DaysLow = 0;
        DaysHigh = 0;
    }

    public List<string[]> StockInformation = new List<string[]>();

    public string Symbol { get; set; }

    private double _Bid;
    public double Bid
    {
        get { return _Bid; }
        set
        {
            // If _Bid < value, change fore color
            _Bid = value;
            DisplayCurrentPrice = String.Format("{0} / {1}", value, Ask);

        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Symbol;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="26" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                <GridViewColumn Header="Symbol" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Symbol}" Width="120" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Bid / Ask" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=DisplayCurrentPrice}" Width="125" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="D.High" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=DaysHigh}" Width="75" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="D.Low" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=DaysLow}" Width="75" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Year Low/High" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=DisplayYearPrice}" Width="100" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListView.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Details" Click="CM_Details_Click"></MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListView.ContextMenu>
    </ListView>
```

So what can I do here to achieve what I am looking for? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Change `ForeColor` of which cell and on what condition?

Comment: Hi Rohit, I would like to change the cell DisplayCurrentPrice, on condition Bid < value = green, or Bid > value = Red

Comment: You either need to add something to your datamodel to signify what color the row should be and use a `DataTrigger`, or use a `IValueConverter` to convert your data into a color for the `Foreground` property. You'll probably need an `IMultiValueConverter` so you can pass both `Bid` and `Value` parameters to it, and have it return your color. That's the same as an `IValueConverter`, except it accepts multiple parameters. :)

Comment: Yea, I understand what needs to be done now. Let's say I have a public  Brush _Bruch {get;set;}. How would I bind that to GridViewColumn? I'm the worst at XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would represent my `StockModel` class:

```
class StockModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // NOTE: You must implement PropertyChanged notification for these properties...
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public decimal Bid { get; set; }
    public decimal Delta { get; set; }  // Change in price over time, +/-

    // Any additional properties you may want here...
}
```

Now, the beauty of WPF comes in the form of [`IValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) classes. These classes allow you to 'transmute' values from one type to another, using the logic you provide.

In our case, we want to bind the `ListViewItem.Foreground` color to the `StockModel.Delta` value. Positive non-zero delta values should give us `Green` and negative non-zero delta values should give us `Red`. Zero can remain `Black` or `White` (depending on your theme's contrast).

So how do we accomplish such a thing? We need to create a `StockColorConverter` class that implements `IValueConverter`:

```
sealed class StockColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Convert a delta value to a brush color.
        var deltaValue = System.Convert.ToDecimal(value);

        if (deltaValue > 0)
            return Brushes.Green;       // Positive
        else if (deltaValue < 0)
            return Brushes.Red;         // Negative 
        else
            return Brushes.Black;       // Zero
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // We can't convert a color to a delta value! This will never be used anyhow.
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Now, you will need to wire this up properly in XAML. So first, let's say you are doing this in your `MainWindow.xaml` file. You will need to add your project's namespace after the existing ones:

```
xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
```

Then, create (or append to) `Window.Resources`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <my:StockColorConverter x:Key="StockColorConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

It's much easier to use `DataTemplate`s to handle the layout of your `ListViewItem`s. The `DataTemplate` determines how each item should be displayed, and what should be displayed:

```
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <!-- These are StockModel objects as our data! -->
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Symbol}"
                           Foreground="{Binding Delta, Converter={StaticResource StockColorConverter}}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

You can see that we are binding `TextBlock.Foreground` to `StockModel.Delta`. Normally that wouldn't work since `decimal` is not equivalent to a `Brush` object. However, using the `StockColorConverter` we created, we can easily apply conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You could add this in your c#

```
public bool ChangeColor {get; set;}

private double _Bid;
public double Bid
{
    get { return _Bid; }
    set
    {
         If (_Bid < value)//, change fore color
              ChangeColor = True;
        _Bid = value;
        DisplayCurrentPrice = String.Format("{0} / {1}", value, Ask);

    }
}
```

Then in xaml

```
       <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="26" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ChangeColor}" Value="True">
                      <Setter Property="ForeColor" Value="Red"/>
                   </DataTrigger >
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```